# Single sign on for several website domains

Tags: multisite, authentication, single-sign-on

We currently have a multisite wordpress setup and would like to separate them out and host each site in its specific country for speed increase. We also will have a domain site that will be an like an application (global). We want each user to be able to log into their country site and also be automatically logged into the app.

What is the best approach to achieve this?